# Is there a way to play a sound note in only one ear of headphone in swift 2.0 using AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, avfoundation, core-audio

I have created a game (Swift 2.0, iOS9) in which a background music is played continuously and various other sounds are played based on user interaction.

But now, I would like to play a certain sound only in the right or left ear-phone, if the player is using head phones.
Is this possible using AVFoundation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you would play a sound in left or right.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        testSound()
    }

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CheckoutScannerBeep", ofType: "mp3")!) // If sound not in an assest
     //let alertSound = NSDataAsset(name: "CheckoutScannerBeep") // If sound is in an Asset

    func testSound(){
        do {
            //        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: (alertSound!.data), fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3) //If in asset
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound as URL) //If not in asset
            audioPlayer.pan = -1.0 //left headphone
            //audioPlayer.pan = 1.0 // right headphone
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay() // make sure to add this line so audio will play
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch  {
            print("error")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice.. All the comments were very useful and it made the code highly readable. A very good answer, thanks again. 
also, could you please indicate the need for the statement audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

Comment: I think the sound in one ear sounds different than when it plays in the other ear. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if audio is being played through headphones before you play that sound with this function

```
func headsetPluggedIn() -> Bool {
    let route = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    return (route.outputs ).filter({ $0.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones }).count > 0
}
```

And you can change the audio to left or right ear with AVAudioPlayer's pan property like this

```
myAudioPlayer.pan = 1
```

set it to -1 for left ear or 1 for right ear

Comment: This was very helpful. I had not thought about checking for headphones before playing the sound. But the point you made, makes a lot of sense..